# What is a shared static library?

Tags: language-agnostic, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Whilst looking into the programming language [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), I encountered the following term in it's roadmap:

> Shared static library (.a)

This seems like an oxymoron to me; I was under the impression that shared libraries were loaded at runtime (with a smaller static library for it's exported symbols linked at compile time), and static libraries were linked at compile time?

**My question is**

What is a `shared static library`?

**Additional Information**

The context this was in was under `File Format Emitters`, sub category `Mach-o` at [this link](http://www.red-lang.org/p/roadmap.html) was the first place I noticed it, but after closer inspection it's mentioned all over the place.

Comment: There is no such thing. Probably an error in the documentation.

Comment: @n.m. are you sure? After closer inspection, it is actually mentioned in multiple places all over the roadmap.

Comment: "Shared static library" is a term used about nine times in the recorded history of the internet, apparently to describe two or three different things. I think the only way to know for sure what Red authors mean is to ask them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Red lead author here) I would say a bad choice of words, probably caused by yet another quick copy/paste of HTML snippets, and poor re-reading. :-)

Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thank you :) thought it seemed odd!